# how to set text in background of control

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to set some default text in background of control (e.g. TreeView, ListView, GridView etc). Text is shown when no item in items control and hides when items control is not empty.

I imagine it like this:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i use the following style for this.

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ItemsControl}" TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <VisualBrush Stretch="None">
                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                            <TextBlock Text="No Data" 
                                       FontFamily="Consolas"
                                       FontSize="16"/>
                        </VisualBrush.Visual>
                    </VisualBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <VisualBrush Stretch="None">
                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                            <TextBlock Text="No Data" 
                                       FontFamily="Consolas"
                                       FontSize="16"/>
                        </VisualBrush.Visual>
                    </VisualBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="{x:Type DataGrid}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ItemsControl}}">
</Style>
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TreeView}" TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ItemsControl}}">
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is likely a `.Background` property on the class.  You can make an element out of it like:

```
<Button.Background>
  <!-- content -->
</Button.Background>
```

This will allow you to place content inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use a VisualBrush if you need a more complex background. You can create a VisualBrush out of any control in WPF. If you want a Brush with Labels in a Grid it can be done.